# Using Laravel for serving multiple domains with one codebase

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to Laravel and now figuring out how to use Laravel for this project i'm working on. I have some ideas about approaching it, and like to know how the experts will do the job.

The case
I'm working on a project which has it's CMS, a informative site and about 35 specialized websites. The CMS, informative site and specialized sites are different on content and design. But all the 35 specialized websites are pretty much the same. The design and layout is identical, but the sites contain different content. Currently all sites have it's own codebase, which makes maintaining it very hard.

I'm now looking for a solution that will use just one codebase. CMS and sites share some functionality and both will have it's own functionality. 
I'm just not sure about how to do this.

The sites run on a dedicated webserver that has DirectAdmin installed on it. Within DirectAdmin it's possible to create a domain pointer. This way I can create a site which shows the correct content by checking the http_host variable. Also, if someday a specialized site needs different functionality than the other, I can also check the http_host. I'm not sure if the has any consequents for SEO and whether it's a neat solution.

I've read about bundles and thinking of using them for the informative- and specialized sites. The "main" applications directory will then host the CMS. site.com/ will then be the cms, site.com/info will show a bundle which hosts the informative site and site.com/special will show a bundle for the specialized sites. 
When use a domain pointer, some domain will show the site of another domain. But I don't think this will work with a bundle when it's located at site.com/(bundle).

I already have a database that distinct content by http_host. I would now like to know how to structure the code (and how to point 35 domains to the right pieces of code).

I hope the experts over here can tell me some of there best practices on how to do this job. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are those sub domains or different domains?

Comment: One way is, create a master router. Depending on request domain, include the sub router specific to that domain. Templates, views, assets all will be same.

Comment: @itachi Those are different domains.

Comment: @itachi what do you mean by master router and sub router? In this case all files will be at the same place right?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to keep 3 projects (one for each kind of site).

You could combine the main site and the informative site they way you proposed (as a bundle), but the only reason to do so is to share something between them, which is probably not the case since they have different design and content. If it's only a matter of having it on "/info", this is achievable by a well designed [Virtual Host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/) configuration (can't give too much direction on that tho).

Although, I would recommend you to keep the informative site on http://info.site.com instead. It feels "right" to me to have different websites on different domains (or subdomains). Some people even advocate this is the correct thing to do, but who knows...

If you have libraries that you may reuse between all projects, I would recommend putting those on a bundle and include that bundle on all projects.

Now, about the 35 specialized sites, you should point all URL's to the same application through Virtual Host's [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias).

On that application, you should defined [Environments](http://laravel.com/docs/install#environments) which let you configure some aspects of it based on the URL. For instance, you can define a different database for each website, create separate log files, languages, anything that is configurable on /application/config. You can also create your own configurations either.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's the design that differs but all sites use pretty much same functionality. It's not only one library that's being used multiple times. That's why I thought it be usefull to share the whole core of laravel include classes etc. Thanks for the tip on ServerAlias.